# Diplay information in Console at every boot

Tags: boot, command-line

Each time I boot the system I would like to display some information in the console.
It must be without the user is logged and after the normal boot sequence (which seems to end with a clear screen).

The information should be generated from a script. Something like

"Welcome to your server. The IP is 1.2.3.4"

I have tried looking at the /etc/rc folders but couldn't really guess the right way to do it.

I am using ubuntu 20.04

UPDATE: Instead of displaying a message in the terminal I considered it would be better to display it when a user logs ind.

This can be done by

1. Creating a script and placing it here: /etc/update-motd.d/99-final
2. Grant execute rights: chmod +x /etc/update-motd.d/99-final

You don't have to call it 99-final though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the message displayed **on a text console** (you are not running a GUI) **before the user logs in**.

One of the simplest methods is to use the `/etc/issue` file or `/etc/issue.d` directory. The `/etc/issue` file contains the default text that is displayed on the console before login prompt. For example what I see on my text console is the following:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS jarek-02 tty3

jarek-02 login:
```

The message in the top line comes from the `/etc/issue` file which has the following contents:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS \n \l
<empty line>
```

`\n` is replaced by hostname of your machine, and `\l` is replaced by TTY name.

You can either replace the contents of `/etc/issue` with your own (but I guess it can be overwritten with a release upgrade, when release changes to 20.04.3 for example), or you can **add** another file by creating a directory `/etc/issue.d` and placing a file with an extension `.issue` there.

For example, when I created a file `/etc/issue.d/01start.issue` with the following contents:

```
<empty line>
Welcome to the server. The IP is: \4
<empty line>
<empty line>
```

the message on my text console looks like this:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS jarek-02 tty3


Welcome to the server. The IP is: 192.168.15.100
    

jarek-02 login:
```

(`\4` is replaced with the IPv4 address of your computer).

You can find more information in `man agetty`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your feedback - I will put it in as a solution even though I found a solution more fitting to my needs.